# Can an ldr be reordered before an ldrex to the same address?

Tags: assembly, arm, shared-memory, atomic, cpu-architecture

In the following instruction sequence:

```
mov r4, r0
add r0, r4, #40
.tryagain:
ldrex   r1, [r0]
add r1, r1, #1
strex   r2, r1, [r0]
cmp r2, #0
bne .tryagain
ldr r1, [r4, #40]
```

We first atomically increment the value at [r4 + 40] by 1. The ldrex will leave the old value in r1.
Then we immediately load the new incremented value at the same address using a normal load (ldr). 
Ignoring the obvious fact that we could just add 1 to r1 after the bne, instead of loading it again, is it possible that the ldr can be reordered by the processor to happen before ldrex?

Comment: In this (hopefully fictitious) example, the fact that there is an address dependency would prevent reordering. Is you actual question whether the load/store hazard checking is done on the base register or the actual address?

Comment: @unixsmurf : Could you please explain the address dependency that prevents the reordering? AFAIU there would be an address dependency if the result of the ldrex was used in the computation of the address in the ldr, which is definitely not the case here. I'll try to explain my thought process which will hopefully explain my actual question: ARM processors do not guarantee that loads are executed in the same order, even if there is an intervening branch. Then is it possible for the later ldr to be executed before the ldrex?

Comment: apologies, address dependency is probably the wrong term. To be honest I tend to just go by the basic rule that a single-threaded program on a single processor must always appear to be executing sequentially. If the second ldr accessed a different address it could certainly be reordered unless an explicit memory barrier was inserted. ARMv8 adds another interesting scenario with the non-temporal load/stores.

Comment: @unixsmurf so in this case, since the address of both ldrex and ldr is the same value - [r4 + 40], the cpu is not allowed to reorder them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from ARM's [Barrier Litmus Tests and Cookbook](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.genc007826/Barrier_Litmus_Tests_and_Cookbook_A08.pdf)

> 7.1 LOAD EXCLUSIVE/STORE EXCLUSIVE AND BARRIERS, Introduction
>
> ... **The instructions do
>   not have any implicit barrier functionality defined as part of their
>   operations** ...

Comment: Barriers concern *memory consistency*, i.e., the ordering across processors for different addresses.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton It's ARM's barriers as in DMB, DSB and ISB. You can use them to force order in an out-of-order executing core. In fact they don't even help across different cores. I probably didn't understand what you mean. This is a nice article from ARM http://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2011/10/19/memory-access-ordering-part-3--memory-access-ordering-in-the-arm-architecture

Comment: @auselen So reordering **is** possible? Also are there any rules regarding reordering two loads from the same address?

Comment: DMB *is* provided for consistency across "all other masters". The basic processor ensures that data accesses in a single program *appear* to occur in program order (this is standard for any modern processor architecture). ISB is necessary even for merely pipelined processors but concerns *instruction* fetch not data read. TLB and Icache coherence guarantees within a single program are often weaker than for just data accesses (self-modifying code and writing to the page table usually require special actions).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton consistency across all other masters is a huge claim. It just makes sure that other will see output from one core in order. You also can't say "basic processor ensures ..." if processor is running on a weak memory model. Anyway all this doesn't matter, what matters is reference and implementation.

Comment: @scottfearn That ARM document says reordering should be possible on a out-of-order core. At least that would be my take. However I don't know if a core does really check the address (never heard or read about it) for reordering purposes. You get a address dependency if you use the output from previous load, which you don't - you use r4. I think it should be possible for core to issue ldr parallel to ldrex/strex. They don't really seem to have any dependency except usage of r1, which can be handled with register renaming.